# Get id of table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a html-table that is actually a chessboard. Something like:

```
<table id="chessboard">
    <tr>
       <td id="A8"></td>
       <td id="B8"></td>
       <td id="C8"></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
       <td id="A7"></td>
       <td id="B7"></td>
       <td id="C7"></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
       <td id="A6"></td>
       <td id="B6"></td>
       <td id="C6"></td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Now I am trying to make a JQuery script that returns the cell id (ie "A8", "B6", etc) once one clickes anywhere on in the table (chessboard). I've tried a lot, but I can't get it to work.

One of the things I tried:

```
$("#chessboard").on("click", function(cell){
    alert(cell.target).attr("id"));

})
```

Anybody got a solution?

Comment: Why did you write `alert(cell.target).attr("id"))`? What do you expect that code to do?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```js
$("#chessboard td").on("click", function(cell){
    alert(this.id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="chessboard">
    <tr>
       <td id="A8">A8</td>
       <td id="B8">B8</td>
       <td id="C8">C8</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
       <td id="A7">A7</td>
       <td id="B7">B7</td>
       <td id="C7">C7</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
       <td id="A6">A6</td>
       <td id="B6">B6</td>
       <td id="C6">C6</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Lack of event delegation may also be a problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - Why would event delegation be needed here?

Comment: Not needed *per se*, but the code in the question does use delegation, albeit not with an explicit selector, so the code in your answer may have a different behavior if the table is populated dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

`cell.target` in this case refers to the DOM element that dispatched the event. DOM elements don't have a `.attr()` method, that is a jQuery object method.

To use it, you'd need to first wrap up your DOM element in a jQuery object:

```
$("#chessboard").on("click", function(e){
    $cell = $(e.target);
    alert($cell.attr('id'));
});
```

Nitpick: Call the `event` something relevant, not `cell`. It'll just confuse you later on.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like...

```
    $('#chessboard').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

The 'this' works like a charm.

Also don't forget to reference the jquery script somewhere in your document:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is only table click, doesn't exactly with td element,

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate

```
  $("#chessboard tr").on("click","td", function(cell){
        alert(this.id);
    })
```

this is the example on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ccdiego5/szhcx9e4/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I've got the answer.

This worked:

```
$("#chessboard td").on("click", function(cell){
    alert(this.id);
})
```